ERROR in build nowinandroid google sample project
I install last version android studio (Iguana)
when I build this project 2 errors occur:
also full build error in file:  https://filebin.net/4m8p6lwvmyd8d9h9/error_build.txt
2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Failed to stop service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService_196285ba-f60d-4000-b519-ef3731265db4'.


Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0

1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Multiple build operations failed.
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@61dec123 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@6f454972 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@351b4015 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@11ca7aac of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@7ee679c6 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@208df8fa of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@70bd15f of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@efb760d of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@1911a214 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@7a98d745 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
...and 17 more failures.
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@61dec123 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@61dec123 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@61dec123 of type D8BackportedMethodsGenerator.Parameters
Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.

build and run project

Can you please check why your gradle instance is not allowed to access this: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml

Clean Project: Go to Build > Clean Project from the Android Studio menu. This will clean all build artifacts and might resolve any dependency conflicts.
Invalidate Caches/Restart: Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and select Invalidate and Restart. This will clear out any cached data that might be causing conflicts.
Check Gradle Configuration: Ensure that your project's Gradle configuration is correct, including the dependencies and Gradle plugin versions specified in your build.gradle files.
Update Gradle Plugin: Make sure you are using the latest version of the Gradle plugin for Android. You can check for updates in your project's build.gradle file.
Update Android Studio: Ensure you are using the latest version of Android Studio, as newer versions often come with bug fixes and improvements that might resolve your issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
